# Moving items from Listbox1 to Listbox2 code

Tags: excel, vba, userform

So, Listbox1 is populated (from another sub, linked to range of cells in the workbook) and users can select (one at a time) items from that Listbox to be shown in Listbox2, using a Command Button (Add) to move them. I've nearly managed to get it perfect. My problem is that if a user **only** selects the final entry in Listbox1, all other possible entries in Listbox1 are removed (blanked out/not visible/cannot be selected).

I want only the entry which has been selected from Listbox1 to be removed from Listbox1 as it appears in Listbox2.

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Add_Click()
Dim i as Integer
    For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
            Me.ListBox2.AddItem Me.ListBox1.List(i)
        End If
    Next i

    For i = Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
            Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem i
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

If there's anything obvious here, I'm really sorry. But these Listboxes have been driving me crazy for about 3 days now.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How exactly are you populating box 1? Btw you can avoid the second loop if the listbox is single select only.

Comment: Listbox1 is populated from a separate sub: ```ListBox1.AddItem Sheets("lookups").Range("H3")```. There are three separate lines/referenced cells. Ideally there would be a dynamically-selected Named Range, but that never got off the ground.

Comment: Have you set the rowsource at all - check the properties - as that can cause problems? I can't replicate your error. How many items does listbox1 have?

Comment: I've read loads of posts about RowSource and have steered clear. My full code for the Listbox1 items is:
```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    If Sheets("EnteredData").Range("E4") = "NDS" Then
            ListBox1.AddItem Sheets("lookups").Range("F3")
            ListBox1.AddItem Sheets("lookups").Range("F4")
            ListBox1.AddItem Sheets("lookups").Range("F5")
        Else
            ListBox1.AddItem Sheets("lookups").Range("H3")
            ListBox1.AddItem Sheets("lookups").Range("H4")
            ListBox1.AddItem Sheets("lookups").Range("H5")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: But there's definitely nothing in RowSource

Comment: I see what you mean about the 2nd loop. I've changed that now and the removing still works (thank you). I'm still getting the same error when the final item is selected though

Comment: It's a single-select list, so add `Exit For` inside each loop once you've hit the selected item

Comment: @Tim Williams - that's worked great. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a single-select list, so try adding `Exit For` inside each loop once you've hit the selected item:

```
Private Sub Add_Click()
    Dim i as Long

    For i = Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
            Me.ListBox2.AddItem Me.ListBox1.List(i) 
            Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```